# `:!sort` unresponsive

Tags: external-command

[image]

I want to randomly sort a file, but it somehow seems to be stuck in a loop or unresponsive. I dinstinctly remember it worked last time, so I must have done something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
:!sort --random-sort
```

Can someone point out if I did something wrong?

Comment: In the future [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not stuck in the loop, it just waits for input.

To make it work you have to send buffer lines to external `sort`, for example, the whole buffer range `%`:

```
:%!sort --random-sort
```